# How to identify all queries in a pending transaction in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, transaction

Let's say I have a pending transaction that shows in `select * from v$transaction`. Is there a way to identify all queries executed so far in the pending transaction?

Comment: It's outside of my control since I'm not the one administering it but I doubt it.

Comment: 11.2.04 -- Padding up to 15 chars

Comment: If this is related to your prior question http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149859/how-can-a-session-be-blocked-by-an-session-that-is-idle are you really looking for all statements that had been executed or are you just trying to identify which row lock is causing the block in the other thread?

Comment: Yep, it is related. Basically I'm trying to find out the query from the blocking session that is responsible for the lock.

Comment: Do you need the query?  Or do you want to know what row is locked?  You can get the row.  Getting the DML statement is generally difficult unless you're the admin that can fire up LogMiner to go through redo logs.

Comment: You recommend looking at v$lock and linking it with v$session then?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can only view the *most recent* SQL of the transaction. Oracle records transactions at the block level, not at SQL level, so this information is not retained.

To see the most recent SQL, join the SES_ADDR column of v$transaction with the SADDR column of v$session. e.g.

```
SELECT a.sid, a.username, b.xidusn, b.used_urec, b.used_ublk, b.status
  FROM v$session a, v$transaction b
  WHERE a.saddr = b.ses_addr
  order by b.used_urec;
```

You can then join the sql_id from v$session with v$sql to see the most recent SQL for the session. e.g.

```
select sql_id,sql_text from v$sql where sql_id in
    (select sql_id from v$session where sid=&sid);
```

You'd need to join the sessionid with the dba_hist_active_sess_history table to see more SQL executed by the session. Even then it will not neccessarily be a complete list, as this view works by periodic polling.

You could use tracing or auditing if you wanted a list of all SQLs for specific sessions, but again this would not be recorded at the transaction level. Perhaps you could compare this result with the start_date or start_scn from v$transaction to figure out which SQLs belonged to which transaction.

Comment: That's definitely a correct answer so I +1d it. The reason I have not accepted it yet is because, in our prod environment, I haven't been able to extract the information about the transaction from dba_hist_sess_history. I'm querying using session_serial# and transaction id. There are rows in with the given serial_number# but not the transaction in question. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flashback info to get information about former DML activities of a given transaction. 
The expectable details depends on wether supplemental logging is activated or not.

```
SELECT * FROM Flashback_Transaction_Query WHERE XID = :transaction_id;
```